# Mongo get average values within aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to get the average value of a array of values.
With the following query I get the following result:
I want to have the average value of the "waardes" array.
Is this possible in the aggregate query:

```
$Query= array(
    array(
        '$match' => array( '$and' => array(                                 
                                    array('ScienceId' => (string)748),
                                    array('type' => 1),
                                    array('day' => (string)2015-08-19),
                                    array('hour' =>  array('$in' => 13)),
                                    array('minute' =>  array('$in' => 11)),
                                    array('values.118.GroepId' =>(int)118),
                                    array('values.118.5.description' =>(string)001_buitentemp),
                                ) 
                ),
    ),
    array(
        '$sort' => array(
            "_id" => -1,
            "Day"   => 1,
            "Hour" => 1,
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$limit' => 10000
     ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            "_id" => array("Science Id" => '748',
                           "Day" => '2015-08-19,
                           "Hour" => '13',
                           "Minute" => '11',
                           "Groep Id" => '$values.118.GroepId",
                           "k" => '$values.'.$groep_id.'.'.$val_id.'.values',
                          ),
            "LastId" => array('$last' => '$_id'),
            "FirstId" => array('$first' => '$_id'),
            "Aantal" => array('$sum' => 1),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            "_id" => '$_id.Science Id',
            "groep" => '$_id.Groep Id',
            "waardes" => '$_id.k',
        )
    ),
);
```

If I run this query: `$result = $col->aggregate($Query);`, I get the following result:

```
{"result":[{"_id":"748","groep":118,"waardes":[20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2]}],"ok":1}
```

Now I want to have the avarage value of the "waardes".
Is this possible within the aggregate query.

If I added `array('$unwind' => '$waardes')` to the query, I get the following error : 
`exception: $unwind:  value at end of field path must be an array'`

This is my document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55d464811a8014df6d8b456d"),
"scienceId" : "748",
"type" : NumberLong(1),
"day" : "2015-08-19",
"hour" : "13",
"minute" : "11",
"values" : {
    "118" : {
        "GroepNaam" : "cel",
        "GroepNummer" : NumberLong(1),
        "GroepId" : NumberLong(118),
        "5" : {
            "description" : "001_buitentemp",
            "values" : {
                "0" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "1" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "2" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "3" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "4" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "5" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "6" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "7" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "8" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "9" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "10" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "11" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "12" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "13" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "14" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "15" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "16" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "17" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "18" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "19" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "20" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "21" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "22" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "23" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "24" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "25" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "26" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "27" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "28" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "29" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "30" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "31" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "32" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "33" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "34" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "35" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "36" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "37" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "38" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "39" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "40" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "41" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "42" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "43" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "44" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "45" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "46" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "47" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "48" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "49" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "50" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "51" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "52" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "53" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "54" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "55" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "56" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "57" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "58" : 20.1999999999999990,
                "59" : 20.1999999999999990
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There strings. You cannot get an average value from a string. There is no type casting in the aggregation framework. Fix the data or use mapReduce.

Comment: Can Mapreduce in the aggregate query?
Is it possible to get an example of mapReduce?

Comment: `mapReduce()` is a seperate method to the `aggregate()` method. Since it uses JavaScript then you can cast a string as a numeric value. But really you should fix your data. And you should produce your coded sample without variable interpolation as well as showing an original document so people have some idea of the structure.

Comment: I changed the values to numbers.  I have nog the following result:  
`{"result":[{"_id":"748","groep":118,"waardes":[22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5,22.5]}],"ok":1} `

Comment: How about you change all the variables in your question and show an original document as well. And there is an [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32092352/edit) link on your question to use for revisions. Please don't post revisions or code in comments. The question is what we want to read.

Comment: Hi Blakes Seven, I changed the original post.

Comment: I really don't understand the point of this code. All it seems to be doing is matching some criteria, sorting in date order, limiting the number of results and then "possibly" removing any duplicate values of a number of fields. You are even throwing away the aggregated fields. Does this actually group anything?